# VBA Outlook Email Formatting

Tags: excel, vba, outlook, signature, office-automation

Whenever I use the below code to generate an email it does not use the default new email formatting. The below code is adding spacing after paragraphs and will not let me insert my default signature without changing the formatting of it as well. I moved mymail.display up and it shows the new mail template with correct formatting and signature however the rest of the code over writes this. Thanks in advance!

```
Sub Email()
'
' Email Macro
'
Sheets("Email").Select
Dim outlookapp As Object
Dim myMail As Object
Dim source_file, to_emails, cc_emails As String
Dim i, j As Integer

ActiveWorkbook.Save
Set outlookapp = CreateObject("outlook.Application")
Set myMail = outlookapp.CreateItem(olMailItem)

myMail.Display
For i = 2 To 6
    to_emails = to_emails & Cells(i, 1) & ";"
    cc_emails = cc_emails & Cells(i, 6) & ";"
    body_emails = body_emails & Cells(i, 5) & vbNewLine
    source_file = source_file & Cells(i, 3)
Next i

source_file = ThisWorkbook.FullName
myMail.CC = cc_emails
myMail.to = to_emails
myMail.Subject = Sheets("Email").Range("B2").Value
myMail.Body = body_emails



'
End Sub
```

Comment: `myMail.HTMLBody = body_emails & myMail.HTMLBody` instead of `myMail.Body = body_emails`.

Comment: This is the closest however now the "vbnewline" is no longer working. Anyway to have it indent the list of items for "cells(i, 5)"?

Comment: Changed vbnewline to "<br/>" and everything works perfectly now thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The existing content of the message body with a signature added is overwritten by using the following line of code:

```
myMail.Body = body_emails
```

First of all, the `Body` property represents a plain text string without any formatting. To preserve formatting in the message body you need to use the [HTMLBody](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.mailitem.htmlbody) property instead.

Second, you need to paste the content (`body_emails`) right after opening `<body>` tag. So, all other HTML markup will be preserved.

Comment: Can the htmlBody still reference cell values instead of having to paste the content in the string for the HTML formatting? Can you preform something like the below or is this functionality lost whenever you use htmlbody?                                                 
For i = 2 To 6
    htmlbody_emails = <body> htmlbody_emails & Cells(i, 5) & vbNewLine </body>                     Next i